# ADF - what's the best way to execute one from a list of Data Flow activities based on a condition

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have 20 file formats and 1 Data Flow activity that maps to each one of them. Based on the file name, I know which data flow activity to execute. Is the only way to handle this through a "Switch" activity? Is there another way? e.g. can I parameterize the data flow to execute by a variable name?:

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain more about your pipeline? do you have 20 files and you want to send them dynamically to one data flow or do you have 20 files and each file will be sent to a different data flow?

Comment: 20 files, each will be sent to its own data flow.

Comment: @SallyDabbah response above

Comment: can  you please explain to me why do you need different dataflow for each file ? this solution does not seem to be scalable. 
Can you please provide more info about your scenario? and how do you parse your files ? is it based on a semantic logic? i think building a dataflow for each file is not a scalable solution and its hard to maintain, have you think about dataflow per file format?

Comment: also, if you want to call dataflows dynamically then you have to do it programmatically this can't be done in the UI, maybe consider Custom activity and in custom activity run some code that will trigger your dataflow. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-python

Comment: @SallyDabbah every file will have its own mappings to a common schema. that's why i went with one data flow per file. is that not correct? afaik, you can't invoke a data flow through a custom activity.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately , there is no option to run one out of list of dataflows based on input condition.

> To perform data migration and transformation for multiple tables, you can use **same dataflow and parameterize the dataflow by providing the table names** either during the runtime or use a control table to hold all the tablenames and inside foreach , call the dataflow activity. In the sink settings, use merge schema option.

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]